# Randomly measured CPU & User time difference of 0 with ThreadMXBean in Spring with AOP

Tags: java, spring, performance, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to measure performance stats for some tasks in Spring, consisting of several method calls each. These performance stats should not include the times needed for database queries. Therefore I intercept DAO methods using a Spring AOP aspect in which I stop the measurement of the task and start a seperate measurement for the database call. Both measurements work, **the problem is, that the CPU&User time obtained by ThreadMXBean sometimes don't increase during one of the different measured sections.** As those sections I mean A) the measurement of the task before a DB call, B) the measurement of the DB call and C) the measurement of the task after the DB Call. I got reasonable measurements for each section but not for all three at the same time. It seems that at least one of them (at random as it seems) shows no increasment in CPU&User time.

In the following is some example code visualizing my problem case:

```
@Api
@Path("task1")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class task1Resource {

    @Autowired
    private MeasurementService measurementService;

    @POST
    public Response startTask(...){
        measurementService.start("task1", false);
        //Transactional service methods with the business logic for task1     
        //are called
        measurementService.end("task1");
        return Response.ok(entity).build();
    }
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class MeasurementService {

    @Autowired
    private MeasurementDAO measurementDao

    public void start(String task, boolean interrupted){
        MeasurementObject measurementObj = new MeasurementObject();
        ThreadMXBean mxBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        if(interrupted){
            //Get the previously persisted measurement object for the task
            measurementObj = measurementDao.get(task);
            //Calculate the differences with the values of the previous section
            measurementObj.calcCpuTimeDifference(mxBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
            measurementObj.calcUserTimeDifference(mxBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
        }else{
            //Initialize
            measurementObj.setTask(task);
            Set<DAOMeasurement> daoCalls = new HashSet<DAOMeasurement>();
            measurementObj.setDaoCalls(daoCalls);
            Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
            measurementObj.setThread(currentThread);
            measurementObj.setCpuTime(mxBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime);
            measurementObj.setUserTime(mxBean.getCurrenThreadUserTime);
        }
        measurementDao.save(measurementObj);
    }

    public MeasurementObject end(String task){
        //Get the measurement object for the task
        MeasurementObject measurementObj = measurementDao.get(task);
        ThreadMXBean mxBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        //Calculate the differences with the values from the start 
        //or the previously calculated differences
        measurementObj.calcCpuTimeDifference(mxBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime());
        measurementObj.calcUserTimeDifference(mxBean.getCurrentThreadUserTime());
        return measurementDao.save(measurementObj);
    }
}

@Aspect
@Component
public class daoAspect {

    @Autowired
    private MeasurementService measurementService;

    @Autowired
    private DAOMeasurementService daoMeasurementService;

    @Before("daoMethods() && !measurementMethods()")
    private void start(Joinpoint jopo){
        Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
        //Get the task measurement object that was started in the same thread
        MeasurementObject measurementObj = measurementService.byThread(currentThread);
        measurementObj = measurementService.end(measurementObj.getTask());
        //Start the measurement for the DB call
        DAOMeasurementObject daoMeasurementObj = daoMeasurementService.start(measurementObj);
    }

    @After("daoMethods() && !measurementMethods()")
    private void end(Joinpoint jopo){
        Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
        /*Please assume here that we only have one dao method
        * (In my more complex case I query the database for 
        * the correct daoMeasurementObject by using additional parameters)             
        * So here we find the DB call measurement object that was started
        * in this thread and end it. */
        DAOMeasurementObject daoMeasurementObj = daoMeasurementService.byThread(currentThread);
        daoMeasurementService.end(daoMeasurementObj);
        //We get the task measurement object for this thread and start it again
        MeasurementObject measurementObj = measurementService.byThread(currentThread);
        measurementService.start(measurementObj.getTask(),true);
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.foo.bar.dao.*(..))")
    public void daoMethods(){}

    @Pointcut("@annotation(Measurement)")
    public void measurementMethods(){} //I annotated the measurement dao classes with this annotation
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class DAOMeasurementService {
    /*This class is identical to the MeasurementService class with the 
    * difference that a DAOMeasurementObject gets a MeasurementObject 
    * reference. But the cpu-&user-times are calculated in the same manner */
}
```

As I said **the general setup works**. The task-measurement starts and ends as it is supposed to and the DAO-method in between gets interrupted by the aspect. Also the measurement seems to work properly as I sometimes get correct values. **The only problem is that sometimes the cpu-&user-times do not change from the beginning of one or two of the three measurements sections to the end of them which results in calculated difference values of 0.**

Furthermore I checked that all of those methods have the same *Thread.currentThread()* and *ThreadMXBean.isCurrentThreadCpuTimeSupported()* and *ThreadMXBean.isThreadCpuTimeEnabled()* return *true* on all measurement points.

I'd be really glad for some help or tips! And if you need some more code or information, feel free to request it.

**Update:**

I tested the system with an `@Around` aspect instead of the `@Before` and `@After` aspects and with multiple runs. The result is still the same. The `ThreadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime` and `ThreadMXBean.getCurrentThreadUserTime` values are randomly not increasing during one to two of the measurement phases but instead they increase in between them. As example: Phase A) the measurement at the start of the task shows a CPU-time of 280801800 and a user-time of 265201700 and when this measurement is stopped during the DAO intercept it again shows a CPU-time of 280801800 and a user-time of 265201700. Then at the start of phase B), the measurment of the DAO method, it shows a CPU-time of 296401900 and a user-time of 280801800. But to the end of the DAO method measurement it still shows the same CPU-time of 296401900 and the same user-time of 280801800. During the complete phase C) the times stay the same as in B).

*-> Could it be the case that the ThreadMXBean only updates its stats in some intervals and not when its methods are called? The phases I try to measure at the moment are relatively short, they have a duration of 1 to 10 milliseconds (using LocalDateTime).*

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2 & answer:**

It seems the answer is that the `ThreadMXBean` updates periodically and that my methods run so fast that the `ThreadMXBean` wasn't updated during their runtime.

I tested this by inserting a `Thread.sleep(200);` command between the start and end of each measurement. The result was that I got updated (and seemingly correct) CPU-time and user-time values for each section I want to measure.

**Update 3:**

Okay after further tries I realized that it's not just a question of the time a thread runs between the measurements. **It seems that the phases, I try to measure, consume insufficient CPU-&user-time to be correctly measured by the `ThreadMXBean`.** I added random database queries inside of the three phases and the measurement seem to work better but there still were random measurement problems. I seem to get the best measurement results with a combination of more workload (consumed cpu-&user-time) and `Thread.sleep(X)`.

But this is not really satisfying. **Does anyone by chances have more detailed information about how accurate the `ThreadMXBean` measures or when it gets updated? Or any ideas how I can find it out?**